# html5 audio player and .aif files on the web

Tags: audio, mp3, html5-audio, ogg, aiff

I have been asked to use aif audio files on a website. I am using jplayer.

- Would there be a noticeable difference using .aif?
- Which browsers support .aif?
- Would you advise using .aif for the web?
- Would it mean I would need 3 versions of each track to cover all Browsers/OS?

Like so:

```
<audio controls>
<source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
<source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
<source src="horse.aif" type="audio/aif">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
 </audio>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Some things I found out: Uncompressed (aif, wav etc) audio files have a high bit rate, so this can lead to intermittent, stuttering playback until the whole file has downloaded. Infuriating and frustrating to the listener.

Also should bear in mind that most users will be listening on a pair of crappy computer
speakers built into a computer monitor. They may be listening on a mobile
phone with a reasonable set of headphones, but won't be impressed if the
sound keeps stopping due to the limited speed of wireless delivery.

Answer (score 0):

The most widely supported format currently is mp3, aiff is supported but you'd need to test target browsers to determine which offer support.

You might also consider [SoundJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/SoundJS), a library I helped develop that lets you play audio across a broad range of browsers and devices using a single code base.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks OJay! I will give your library a go on another project :) Are you able to answers some of my other questions?

Answer (score 0):

[Check your own browser](http://jplayer.org/HTML5.Audio.Support/).

I could not find a comprehensive list like you have asked for. So this is the second best.